# How should I punctuate/capitalize the following question?

Tags: punctuation, questions, question-mark

Is the following question punctuated/capitalized correctly?

> “What’s that, a dishrag?”

Or should it be two questions?

> “What’s that? A dishrag?”

Or would a third option be best? Thanks!

Comment: A third option could be "Is that a dishrag?"

Comment: @WeatherVane That's true. However, if we stick with the original wording, what should the capitalization/punctuation be? Thanks!

Comment: A third option could be “What’s that—a dishrag?” using an [em dash](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/dash-and-em-dash). The capitalization is correct, and this [punctuation guide](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/punctuation) may interest you.

Comment: @Ah, I like “What’s that—a dishrag?” I think I'll use that one. Since it's a comment, I can't mark your answer as the one I chose. If you want, copy and paste your answer, and I'll be more than happy to mark it the one. 

Comment: There's also *What's that; a dishrag?* and *What's that . . . a dishrag?* Or even *What's that (a dishrag)?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capitalization is correct, and a third option you could consider is

> “What’s that—a dishrag?”

using an [em dash](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/dash-and-em-dash).

This [punctuation guide](https://www.lexico.com/en/grammar/punctuation) may interest you.